How to measure unreclaimable memory of Azure Pipeline build agent running as Kubernetes pod
We have a setup where Azure DevOps Pipelines self hosted agents are running as Kubernetes pods so that we can run multiple build agents on a single Azure VM.
Now I want to measure the maximum memory consumption during certain pipeline jobs. My goal is to figure out how much memory a certain job needs at least to run without being killed by K8s due to OOM.
For that I have written a script that starts at the beginning of a pipeline job and measures every couple of seconds the current memory till the job end. At the end the measured data is provided as pipeline artifact for later analysis.
Since this is Kubernetes I cannot use top, free, etc. Instead I am parsing the memory.stat file (cgroups v2) for the Kubernetes pod specific cgroup.
Out of that memory.stat file I am summing up following values:

active_file
active_anon
slab_unreclaimable
unevictable

I have now executed a couple of test runs but I get very diverge max values although running always the same pipeline on the same Git repo commit.
Is something wrong with the way how I am computing the max unreclaimable memory or is there maybe even some sort of (temporary) memory leak in the Azure DevOps build agent when it has already run many pipelines between the memory measurements?
I appreciate any advice knowing that this topic is very complex.

As a starting point, have you considered using Lens or OpenLens to check the memory usage of the pods?

There are a few factors that could be contributing to the variability in your measurements. For example, some processes might temporarily use more memory, causing spikes that could be captured in your measurements. Kubernetes itself can introduce some variability in memory usage due to its internal processes and the way it manages resources. You can try kubectl top to check the resource consumption for pods.

I just have another idea related to this problem. Can I assume following: Let's say in 5 runs I get the following max memory consumption: 2GB, 3GB, 2.5GB, 5GB, 4GB. If I now take the 2GB (plus some buffer) shouldn't that be the minimum amount of memory required because for the other runs there is really some memory consumed that can be freed up on demand.
PS. I am in parallel looking also into "kubectl top" and "Lens"

As per Capture resource utilization details:

When using Azure DevOps Services, you can see resource utilization in the logs, including disk usage, memory usage, and CPU utilization, by enabling verbose logs. When the pipeline completes, search the logs for Agent environment resources entries for each step.

Example - using Azure DevOps services (cloud) and build agent v3.246.0:

To configure verbose logs for a single run, you can start a new build by choosing Run pipeline and selecting Enable system diagnostics:


From what understood when trying this out this only shows me the memory consumption of the whole VM but not the pod.
